# How to show some content in specific condition in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I am using SlidingDrawer in viewpager but i want to show this drawer only when middle fragment is active.

See the below image

[image]

I don't want to use sliding drawer inside the second fragment because i am using transparent background in all three fragments and sliding drawer does not hide its contents properly when closing.

Comment: You can add OnPageChangeListener on you pager and change the visibility of sliding drawer to gone when the selected page is middle one and visible when other pages are selected.

Comment: will middle fragment overlaps that drawer ?

Comment: That will depend on how you arrage all views in your layout. e.g. if you are using Relative layout then put sliding drawer on the bottom.

Comment: No i am asking that when i will use sliding drawer in viewpager does it hide by the fragments ?